# Sort text file by using last name

Tags: php

I have a php little script that sorts the data from a text file by using the first name but I need to sort by last name, the text file looks like this

```
name1,last1,email1
name2,last2,email2
name3,last3,email3
```

how can I sort the text file by using last name?

```
$data = file($file_path);
natsort($data);
file_put_contents($new_file_path, implode("\n", $data));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the 2nd column, put it in an array and sort it. Then using the key from the newly sorted array build the result and save it to the new file.

```
$rows = array();
$result = '';
$data = file($data_path);

foreach($data as $key => $val) {
    $rowarray = explode(",", $val);
    $rows[] = $rowarray[1];
}

asort($rows);

foreach($rows as $key => $val) {
    $result .= trim($data[$key]) . "\r\n";
}

file_put_contents($new_file_path, $resultstring);
```

Comment: Do you have some sample data that you are passing in? When that notice happens, what does `$val` hold?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to sort on one field, then you need to split on the `','` and use `usort`.

```
$data = file($file_path);
usort($data, function($a, $b){
    $a = explode(',', $a);
    $b = explode(',', $b);

    return strnatcmp($a[1], $b[1]);
});
file_put_contents($new_file_path, implode("\n", $data));
```